# HTML canvas changing colors unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a grid with HTML canvas. I have written the following code. Everything works correctly at first, but as soon as the window is resized, the color of the grid lines changes color for some reason.

If you are unable to reproduce the behavior, [here is a video of the behavior](https://vimeo.com/266949223).

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
});

var xOffset = 0;
var yOffset = 0;
var gridSize = 75;

ctx.lineWidth = 2;

function draw() {

  ctx.fillStyle = '#e8e8e8';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  ctx.strokeStyle = '#7a7f7e';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  for (var i = 0; i < window.innerWidth + gridSize; i += gridSize) {

    ctx.moveTo(i + xOffset % gridSize, 0);


    ctx.lineTo(i + xOffset % gridSize, window.innerHeight);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < window.innerHeight + gridSize; i += gridSize) {


    ctx.moveTo(0, i + yOffset % gridSize);

    ctx.lineTo(window.innerWidth, i + yOffset % gridSize);
  }
  ctx.stroke();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is to move the ctx.lineWidth = 2 inside the requestAnimationFrame. When I change the width manually I see the same behavior, the line width defaults. So here is working fiddle that solves your problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/skgn9q51/2/

```
function draw() {

  ctx.fillStyle = '#e8e8e8';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
 ctx.lineWidth = 2;
......
```

I think this behavior is intended. So to get your lineWidth out you might need to resort to save() restore();